# Why does Woocommerce get_meta function on product object always return empty result when key is _product_attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the following code to output `_product_attributes` meta value:

```
       $product_id = get_the_ID();
       $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
       
       $product_attr = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes',true);
       error_log(print_r($product_attr,1)) //Outputs _product_attributes array
    
       $product_attr = $product->get_meta('_product_attributes');
       error_log(print_r($product_attr,1)) //Outputs false even when _product_attributes meta is set in the database and it is output in the previous step
```

Why does `$product->get_meta('_product_attributes')` return false where as `get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes',true)` return the meta value correctly? I have tested on multiple products and multiple woocommerce installations.